# How to use where in list items

Tags: sql, linq

I have a database as below:

```
TABLE_B: 
ID    Name      LISTID
1     NameB1    1
2     NameB2    1,10 
3     NameB3    1025,1026
```

To select list data of table with ID. I used:

```
public static List<ListData> GetDataById(string id)
{
    var db = Connect.GetDataContext<DataContext>("NameConnection");  
    var sql = (from tblB in db.TABLE_B
               where tblB.LISTID.Contains(id)
               select new ListData
               {
                   Name= tblB.Name,
               });
    return sql.ToList();
}
```

When I call the function:
GetDataById("10") ==> Data return "NameB2, NameB3" are not correct. 
The data correct is "NameB2". Please help me about that?
Thanks!

Comment: `tblB.LISTID.Contains` checks if a substring matches, if you want to compare the whole string use `tblB.LISTID == id`

Comment: Hi @TimSchmelter, 
Thanks for your answer. I want use Contains to compare width list items (10,1,2,3) to get data.
EX: The movie under multiple categories

Comment: This is happening because LISTID is a string column (varchar) and `Contains` translates to `Like` in sql server.

Comment: Hi @MihailStancescu,
Thanks you. Do you have any solutions about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `10` will cause unintended matches because LISTID is a string/varchar type, as you already saw, and the Contains function does not know that there delimiters that should be taken into account.

The fix could be very simple: surround both the id that you are looking for *and* LISTID with extra commas.

So you will now be looking for `,10,`.
The value `,10,` will be found in `,1,10,` and not in `,1025,1026,`

The LINQ `where` clause then becomes this:

```
where ("," + tblB.LISTID + ",").Contains("," + id + ",")
```